# Is it possible to print/log a function in java?

Tags: javascript, java, logging

When I was exploring ES6, I came across this keyword being used.
If used `console.log(this)` and object contains a function, then function code is being printed/logged. It seemed pretty interesting to me. I was exploring if a similar way of printing/logging of function is possible for java language. Unfortunately, I could not find any.

1. Is it possible to print function in java?
2. If not any reason why it is prohibited in java? [Is it because java doesn't use a callback mechanism?]

Comment: To your second question: Ask the developer at Oracle (and Sun) why :-)

Comment: System.out.println("") outputs to stdout. There is no way of retrieving the original source code of a java function as it is discarded after compilation (actually, transpiling occurs, not compiling, but it's close enough). It is possible to dump the resulting bytecode, though I doubt if that'll help.

Comment: Unfortunately there's no (simple / official) way to traverse or visit bytecode elements easily, in Kotlin it is easy as the new IR compiler let's the pre-compilation plugins to traverse through the elements change its signature and add more things to it, as [an example](https://github.com/bnorm/kotlin-power-assert#example) this plugin shows visual representation of the error assertions (runtime values of each expression). But there's no easy way to do so in Java, badluck :(

Answer (score 0):

Interesting.
In ES6 , Functions declared and assigned to functions can be called upon later using the variable .

```
var e= function() {
      a= 5; 
      b = 7;
     console.log(a * b);}; 
    console.log(e) // prints the function..interesting ,cant think of any great value tbh.
    e();   // executes the function
```

In java if you want to assign a method to a variable , there are various ways using  FunctionalInterfaces  . viz . Function,Consumer, BiConsumer .

But you will not get the original source syntax in these variables. You will have to parse the bytecode (.class files ) . If you need to get a handle on source.

Answer (score 0):

In ECMAscript, everything that is not a primitive is an Object, so your function is also just an Object. That is also the reason why you can easily output it to the console using the `this` keyword.

This is simply not the case in Java. Remember that Java and JavaScript are very different languages. Also, Java has to be compiled while ECMAscript does not. So even if you find a way and write a bunch of custom code to make this possible, the end result will not be an exact representation when decompiled.